# Python FightSequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, wing-ide

I'm trying to build a simple Fight Sequence, where a user pick's their "Class" (Warrior, Archer, Mage), as well as the monster they want to fight (Goblin, Troll, Orc).

The code I have so far is:

```
import random 

def choosePlayerClass():

    class Warrior:
        health = 100
        attack = 10
        defense = 10

    class Archer:
        health = 75
        attack = 15
        defense = 7

    class Mage:
        health = 50
        attack = 20
        defense = 5


    playerChoice = input("What class do you want to be? (Warrior, Archer, Mage)? ")
    if playerChoice == "Warrior":
        Player = Warrior()
    elif playerChoice == "Archer":
        Player = Archer()
    elif playerChoice == "Mage":
        Player = Mage()

    return Player

def chooseMonsterClass():

    class Goblin:
        health = 25
        attack = 10
        defense = 5
        description = "Goblin"

    class Troll:
        health = 50
        attack = 13
        defense = 7
        description = "Troll"

    class Orc:
        health = 75
        attack = 15
        defense = 10
        description = "Orc"  

    monsterChoice = input("What kind of monster do you want to fight? (Goblin, Troll, Orc)? ")

    if monsterChoice == "Goblin":
        Monster = Goblin()
    elif monsterChoice == "Troll":
        Monster = Troll()
    elif monsterChoice == "Orc":
        Monster = Orc

    return Monster

def fightSequence():
    Player = choosePlayerClass()
    Monster = chooseMonsterClass()
    encounter = 1
    turn = 'player'
    while encounter == 1:
        if turn == 'player':
            action = input("What would you like to do (Attack)? ")
            if action == 'Attack':
                encounter = humanAttack(Player)
                turn = 'monster'
        elif turn == 'monster':
            encounter = monsterAttack(Monster)
            turn = 'player'


fightSequence()
```

And I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 4.1\src\debug\tserver_sandbox.py", line 109, in 
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 4.1\src\debug\tserver_sandbox.py", line 102, in fightSequence
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 4.1\src\debug\tserver_sandbox.py", line 63, in humanAttack
builtins.NameError: global name 'Monster' is not defined

Thanks!

Comment: the Orc is missing parentheses, just a FYI

Comment: Sounds like you have an error in your `humanAttack` method. But how curious, there's no `humanAttack` method defined in all the code you have so far! Are you holding out on us?

Comment: See: http://jsfiddle.net/EM4AA/4/ Archer OP!

Comment: Found the missing parenthese, danke for that.

Comment: Archer is always OP, because Legolas is my favorite. 

And I was holding out on you @Kevin. I'm so sorry, but it's all fixed now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you initialize the Monster variable:

```
if monsterChoice == "Goblin":
    Monster = Goblin()
elif monsterChoice == "Troll":
    Monster = Troll()
elif monsterChoice == "Orc":
    Monster = Orc()
```

but what if none of those are true and none of the if statements are entered?  You should set your variable with a default value before the if statements so that the case where some nonsense is entered by the user is handled:

```
Monster = DefaultRace
if monsterChoice == "Goblin":
    Monster = Goblin()
elif monsterChoice == "Troll":
    Monster = Troll()
elif monsterChoice == "Orc":
    Monster = Orc()
```

Better yet put the whole thing in a loop and ask the user to enter a valid race when a nonsense race is given.

```
while True:
    monsterChoice = input("What kind of monster do you want to fight? (Goblin, Troll, Orc)? ")
    if monsterChoice in ["Goblin","Troll","Orc"]:
        break
    else:
        print "Unrecognized race requested, please select one of Goblin, Troll, Orc."
```

Comment: another alternative is adding `else: Monster = DefaultRace` to the `if` clause

Comment: This is fine and all, and I still made these changes, but for some reason I still get an error saying:

`builtins.NameError: global name 'Monster' is not defined`

Comment: @Keyfer oops I made a typo, Monster needs to have a default value not monsterChoice.

Comment: @AdamCadien I did, and even if the user was to enter a value that was defined, I still get that error.

Comment: It looks like the error actually occurs in the function humanAttack(), the variable Monster was not set properly there.

Comment: Ahh, I found the problem:

`def humanAttack(Player)` was changed to:

`def humanAttack(Player, Monster)`

Answer (score 0):

You want a global declaration, `global Monster` at the beginning, in either the function `chooseMonsterClass` or in `fightSequence`. Try both (at once). so it should be:

```
import random 

def choosePlayerClass():

    class Warrior:
        health = 100
        attack = 10
        defense = 10

    class Archer:
        health = 75
        attack = 15
        defense = 7

    class Mage:
        health = 50
        attack = 20
        defense = 5


    playerChoice = input("What class do you want to be? (Warrior, Archer, Mage)? ")
    if playerChoice == "Warrior":
        Player = Warrior()
    elif playerChoice == "Archer":
        Player = Archer()
    elif playerChoice == "Mage":
        Player = Mage()

    return Player

def chooseMonsterClass():
    global Monster
    class Goblin:
        health = 25
        attack = 10
        defense = 5
        description = "Goblin"

    class Troll:
        health = 50
        attack = 13
        defense = 7
        description = "Troll"

    class Orc:
        health = 75
        attack = 15
        defense = 10
        description = "Orc"  

    monsterChoice = input("What kind of monster do you want to fight? (Goblin, Troll, Orc)? ")

    if monsterChoice == "Goblin":
        Monster = Goblin()
    elif monsterChoice == "Troll":
        Monster = Troll()
    elif monsterChoice == "Orc":
        Monster = Orc

    return Monster

def fightSequence():
    global Monster
    Player = choosePlayerClass()
    Monster = chooseMonsterClass()
    encounter = 1
    turn = 'player'
    while encounter == 1:
        if turn == 'player':
            action = input("What would you like to do (Attack)? ")
            if action == 'Attack':
                encounter = humanAttack(Player)
                turn = 'monster'
        elif turn == 'monster':
            encounter = monsterAttack(Monster)
            turn = 'player'


fightSequence()
```